# Fujifilm Xt200 lens error with Viltrox 23mm/f 1.4 lens

Tags: lens, fujifilm

I just bought my first lens, an Viltrox 23mm/f1.4 for my Fujifilm Xt200 camera and I have this error where the display starts flickering and then the LENS ERROR appear and can't figure out the problem.
I checked the compatibility before I bought it and specified my camera model. I updated the firmware on both, camera and lens and still no improvement.
I can't figure it out.

Comment: Does your camera do this with any other lens? Does the lens do this with any other camera?

Comment: With the kit lens, Fujinon Aspherical lens 15-45mm/f3.5-6.5 it acts normal, no problem at all. The Viltrox lens I didn't try with another camera because I don't have access to other camera so I don't have the possibility to test it. So this I don't know